# Game of Battleships - Javascript guidance

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, if-statement

I am in a little need of guidance for a game of Battleships written purely in javascript.

My game consists of pre-made grid of 7 table rows with 7 table datas (7x7) which is built up like this:

```
[00][01][02][03][04][05][06]
[10][11][12][13][14][15][16]
[20][21][22][23][24][25][26]
[30][31][32][33][34][35][36]
[40][41][42][43][44][45][46]
[50][51][52][53][54][55][56]
[60][61][62][63][64][65][66]
```

I have only one ship at the moment which goes somewhere on the map randomly and it set horizontally on 3 fields. The code to make that happen goes like this:

```
  var location1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 48);
  var location2 = location1+1
  var location3 = location2+1
```

I then have a code so I have to click each tile to find where the ship is and I get a message if it's a hit/miss.

My questions is, I have to have 3 ships put on the map horizontally/vertically and I need some guidance in what would be the best way to do so. I'm sure I could create few more variables called location 4,5,6 and so on but I think here would be best to put the 3 ships in an array.

Could you provide me with some help what would be the best approach to wrap 3 ships in simpler code?

Comment: Aside from positioning ships, you should post your code on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), from the look of it there's a lot that could be improved.

Comment: you do realize your ship can go from, for example, 26 to 27 right now (which does not exist)?

Comment: Hi Johannes H, yes that's another issue I am aware of, I just wanted to see if I could get something to start on with the ships. I will check Code Review too, thanks @Nit

Comment: Generate array of possible valid starting locations (i.e. _n, n+1, n+2_ must all exist and be empty for `n` to be a valid starting location), choose random item from array. Re-generate array for next ship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use objects to keep everything neatly organized. You can also create a mtheod to place the ship on the field inside that object. There is way more you can do to improve your code, but take this as a start:

```
// direction: true = hor, false = vert - nicer solutions than "magic numbers" are possible
function Ship (size, direction) { 
    this.coveredFields = [];
    this.place         = function (sizeY, sizeX) { // sizeX & sizeY: size of fields in both dimensions

        // pick randomly within our limits
        var locationX;
        var locationY;
        if (direction) {
            locationX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sizeX - 1 - size));
            locationY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sizeY - 1));
        } else {
            locationX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sizeX - 1));
            locationY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sizeY - 1 - size));
        }

        // TODO: check that we don't cross/overlap other ships
        // ...

        // setting locations
        for (var i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
            if (direction) {
                this.coveredFields.push(locationY * 10 + locationX + i)
            } else {
                this.coveredFields.push((locationY + i) * 10 + locationX)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then create your 3-field long horizontal ship using `var ship1 = new Ship(3,false)`; place it un your field using `ship1.place(7,7)`; and access the fields that are covered using `ship1.coveredFields` (which is an array that contains all fields)

If this is too complex for you, just use an array for each chip's locations (`var ship1 = [location1, location2, ... ]`) - but OOP is most likely the nicest way to do this.

---

Another recommendation: describe your field by a two-dimensional array (that is, an array that contains arrays). then, store your ships inside that array, instead of the coordinates inside your ships. This also makes placing without overlapping easier, and checking for hit or miss.

If you don't want to do that because it's above your current skill level, you should consider to store at least each dimension separately instead of generating one number out of both. You can use either arrays with two elements each for each point (first value being, x, second y), or objects that look like this: `{x : 5, y : 3}`

Comment: Hi Johannes, that clearly gives me more than enough to keep working on. Thanks alot for your thorough explanations. Appreciate it.

Comment: @SmáriAlfreðsson Glad I could help! check my latest edit for a fixed version of calculating all positions the ship covers - I forgot to actually increas the nubmer for each field ;)